# FusionAuth on Docker - Default login credentials

Tags: fusionauth

I am testing FusionAuth on Docker. FusionAuth container starts successfully and `localhost:9011` shows a login page.

[image]

What are the default credentials for authenticaiton? Spent sometime searching in the documentation, but couldn't find any mention about default login credentials.

Answer (score 2):

When you first started up FusionAuth, you should have seen the "FusionAuth Setup Wizard" screen. That's where you set up the first account, which is an admin account.

Here's the 5 minute setup guide which walks you through all the screens and through setting up your first application: https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/5-minute-setup-guide

Here's the section about the setup wizard (in the second half: https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/5-minute-setup-guide#complete-maintenance-mode-and-the-setup-wizard )

Hope this helps.

Comment: From the documentation, that' how I expected it to work. But I didn't see any setup wizard screen after deploying the application using `docker-compose`. I see login screen when I access the application for the first time

Comment: Weird, did you perhaps connect to an existing database?